# Какие инструменты мне понадобятся для написание "сложного" Telegram бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я являюсь тестировщиком в одной из компании. Мы используем Redmine для получения задач. Чтобы каждый раз не обновлять страницу (F5), я написал телеграмм бота (на Python) который присылает мне уведомления когда мне приходит задача. Для этого я использую API ключ внутри Redmine и свой ID, чтобы бот присылал мне задачи которые повешены конкретно на меня. Но проблема в том, что данный бот работает только "для меня". Я же хочу сделать его доступным для всех сотрудников компании, т.е. поместить его на сервер компании (для работы 24/7) и чтобы каждый сотрудник который зайдёт на этого бота (в телеграмме), мог отправить свой уникальный API ключ с Redmine и свой ID, бот бы принимал данную информацию и присылал бы уведомления каждый раз, когда на этого человека приходила задача.

В своем боте "для себя" я использовал данные библиотеки:

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext
from redminelib import Redmine
```

Т.е. что я хочу:
Создать телеграмм бот для компании, который принимает уникальный ключ сотрудника и после этого присылает ему уведомления в этого же бота.

```
Пример:
Пользователь: /start
Бот: Введите свой API
Пользователь: *вводит свой уникальный API ключ* (прим. "20875048Sfhs874982749018274")
Бот: Введите свой ID
Пользователь: *вводит свой уникальный ID профиля* (прим. "353")
Бот: *начинает присылать задачи в таком виде* https://ibb.co/Sn8b6yL
```

С какими проблемами я столкнулся?

1. Что мне нужно, чтобы бот различал разных сотрудников и мог работать сразу с 20-30 людьми? (нужна идентификация по мобильному телефону?)
2. Для того, что бы бот хранил в себе 2 параметра (ключ API и ID) мне нужно будет использовать какую то базу данных или хватит переменных? Если использовать переменные, как сделать каждую переменную для конкретного пользователя? (что бы переменная не перезаписывалась с вводом данных нового пользователя).

Буду рад любым примерам с просторов интернета, видеороликам или советами "что почитать".

Comment: Бот может получить номер телефона через специальную кнопку (ее нужно на прислать на клавиатуре). Использовать базу данных, минимум sqlite, но можно и mysql/oracle/postgresql. Думаю, еще понадобится работа с потоками или асинхронным кодом, чтобы бот мог посылать уведомления сотрудникам (например, время от времени проверять таблицу в базе с заданиями и рассылать тем, у кого новое задание появилось)

Comment: Звучит сложно, но попробовать наверное стоит. Просто я когда писал для себя бота, это было довольно просто, я подключил библиотеку Redmine, ввел свои данные API ключа что бы миновать авторизацию и свой ID (собственно что бы программа знала, какие задачи конкретного пользователя мне нужны) и все. Я включал бота в начале рабочего дня, он присылал мне задачи которые у меня уже имелись и присылал новые в течение рабочего дня.

Comment: Для ваших пользователей тоже будет все просто :) А вот вам придется потрудиться :) Для другой библиотеки телеграм-ботов делал прототип для создания напоминаний, там тоже база данных и отправка уведомлений, может быть полезной: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/8099e231d477fc78c88ff989fb769dedfa7f36fc/telegram_bot_examples/reminder А тут пример отправки телефона юзера через специальную кнопку: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8099e231d477fc78c88ff989fb769dedfa7f36fc/telegram_bot_examples/send_contact_or_location.py#L19

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы решить задачу как отличать разных пользователей, отдельная авторизация по телефону не нужна. Когда пользователь присоединяется к боту, то он уже уникально идентифицируется по `chat_id` (в обработчике достаете из `update.message.chat_id`).

Авторизация по телефону нужна, только если вы хотите именно что отдельную авторизацию по телефону, для самой задачи поддержки нескольких пользователей это не нужно.

Собственно, чтобы добавить поддержку нескольких пользователей нужно сделать следующее. Сейчас у вас в боте скорее всего есть глобальные переменные для ключа и id (допустим они называются `api_key` и `profile_id`. Они хранят значение для одного пользователя - вас.

Замените это на `dict` такой структуры:

```
{
  'user1-chat-id': {
     'api_key': 'ключ1',
     'profile_id': 'id1'
  },
  'user2-chat-id': {
     'api_key': 'ключ2',
     'profile_id': 'id2'
  },
}
```

и допустим вы эту новую глобальную переменную, которая будет хранить все ключи и идентификаторы назовете `all_keys`. Изначально ее инициализируете пустым словарем:

```
all_keys = {}
```

Теперь во всех местах где вы использовали `api_key` нужно использовать `all_keys[update.message.chat_id]['api_key']`, т.е. вместо:

```
def set_api_key_handler(update, context):
    api_key = update.message.text
```

делайте:

```
def set_api_key_handler(update, context):
    # сначала проверяем создавали ли мы уже запись с ключами для пользователя
    # с этим chat_id. Если нет, то создаем.
    if update.message.chat_id not in all_keys:
       all_keys[update.message.chat_id] = {}
    all_keys[update.message.chat_id]['api_key'] = update.message.text
```

Аналогично для `profile_id`. И при использовании `Redmine` API тоже используем значения из `all_keys` для текущего пользователя идентифицированного по `chat_id`.

Такое решение будет работать так же как сейчас у вас работает, т.е. до перезагрузки бота. При перезапуске, `all_keys` сотрется и пользователям заново нужно будет вводить ключи и идентификаторы. Для этого нужно будет добавить проверку есть ли для текущего `chat_id` данные и если нет запрашивать повторно, так как делается при старте. Если хочется, чтоб бот не терял информацию при перезапуске, нужно при изменении информации (т.е. во всех точка где делается запись типа `all_keys[update.message.chat_id]['api_key'] = update.message.text` сохранять это значение в БД, а при старте бота читать все значения из БД и заполнять ими `all_keys`.