# Как в боте хранить индивидуальные переменные для каждого пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Написал бота, который генерирует случайное число, отправляет его пользователю, и пользователь должен отправить это же число в ответ, иначе будет "Ошибка".
Проблема в том, что когда несколько пользователей будут использовать бота, у них будет одно число на всех. Например: первому пользователю пришло число 34, он не отвечает, затем в бота зашел второй пользователь, ему пришло число 89, после этого первый пользователь пишет ответ "34" и ему приходит сообщение "Ошибка".
Как сделать так, чтобы для каждого пользователя было индивидуальное число?

```
import telebot
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])


def process_start(message):
    global n
    n = random.randint(1, 100)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, str(n))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, question)
    
def question(message):
    if message.text == str(n):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Правильно")

        process_start(message)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ошибка")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, question)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Для нескольких пользователей имеет смысл использовать базу данных, к данным каждого пользователя обращаться по id или имени пользователя. Без базы данных - использовать словарь, откуда (опять же по id или имени) будет получаться информация конкретного пользователя.

Comment: Здесь отвечал на подобный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267540/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-telegram-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0